# How to combine two keys as a hotkey with Autohotkey?

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey, hotkeys, combine

I want to combine Left windows key with printscreen, for on my mouse xbutton2.

i can't get any further than 
Xbutton2::Lwin

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

For mapping to XButton2:

```
Lwin & PrintScreen::MouseClick , XButton2
```

For mapping from XButton2:

```
XButton2::Send, {LWin down}PrintScreen{LWin up}
```

AutoHotkey references:

- [Remapping Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)
- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Send Keys & Clicks](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)

Comment: Thanks man ! thanks for the help, i just want in the other way around. Like i want to press Xbutton2, to activate Lwin & Printscreen at the same time for a screen shot.

Comment: Added more stuff to try.